# Custom 404 error page -- for PHP pages only

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a personalized page for 404 with htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

It works fine, but it takes everything .jpg, .js, .css etc...
I would like it to just take the .php and do a normal 404 error for all others.

I didn't find that option anywhere.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you mean by "it takes everything"? 404 is a response code for any HTTP request that is not found, no matter that is php request or an image.

Comment: what I mean is that if i do www.example.com/img/errorimg.jpg he is going to lead me to www.example.com/404.php, and I don't want that...

Comment: You can try implementing this with URL Rewriting (mod_rewrite) -- redirect requests to any non-existing .php file to your custom 404.php -- that's possible (3 or 4 lines only)

Comment: why don't you want that?

Comment: @Your Common Sense I want that for example I do a mistake in the call of an image, or a js, or whatever... In the console it will do an error `<!DOCTYPE html...` instead of `file xxx not found` and it's quite annoying when we do a duplication of the structure.

Comment: Only **25** downvotes? Why did you stop? Got tired? grew up? I think you can get better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure but give this a try:

```
<Files ~ "\.php$">
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
</Files>
```

Quote from [Files Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#files) documentation:

> The <Files> directive limits the scope of the enclosed
>   directives by filename.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible approaches to this, but I would do one of the following:

You can use `mod_rewrite`, as suggested by @LazyOne, to redirect only files with a `.php` extension to your custom document:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Only redirect to error for files that don't exist
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /404.php [L]
```

Or you can direct everything through the PHP error handler as you already do, and use PHP to determine whether the requested resource is a PHP script or not:

```
<?php

  if (strtolower(substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'], -4)) != '.php') {
    // If the requested resource does not have a .php extension, include the standard error doc and exit
    include '404.html';
    exit;
  }

  // Handle .php 404s here
```

The disadvantage of this second approach is that you may need to rewrite the standard error document so that it used PHP to get dynamic information to display to the user, such and the requested resource path.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing the [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), you can easily check the ending of the file that resulted in an error and then throw a header to a normal 404 if it doesn't correspond to your needs or just render a different 404

Put this in your 404.php file

```
$bad_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$bad_extension = substr(strrchr($bad_url,'.'),1);

if($bad_extension != "php"){
    //Not PHP
}else{
    //PHP
}
```