# how to get the url entered from address bar when it is entered manually after domain name in PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Assuming my website name is www.example.com which is written in php.
When I type www.example.com is displays the page. But when I type **www.example.com/content/somepage.html** it says 404 page not found which is correct since it doesn't exist.

Now if the user types this **www.example.com/content/somepage.html** manually I shouldn't redirect to error 404 page but rather I need **content/somepage.html** this value which I can process it further which is my requirement.

Usually index.php is the first page which gets invoked is there any way I can get the value entered after **www.example.com**

**content/somepage.html** is just an example but it can be anything. So what ever is present after www.example.com I need to fetch it.

[Sample Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8ih8n7urm16qke/sample.rar?dl=0)

I am using wamp and  these 2 files are present in www root folder

**index.php**

```
<?php 

    echo 'The Uri is : '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    echo '<br /><br />';

    if(isset($_SERVER['path']))
        echo 'The parameter is : '.$_SERVER['path'];

?>
```

**.htaccess file**

```
DirectroyIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Using mod_rewrite seems like overkill (and judging by the number of questions asked about rewrite rules, its easy to break). I'd go with an ErrorDocument handler - e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631496/custom-404-error-page-for-php-pages-only

Comment: @symcbean I saw it but didn't understand can you please say what changes should I make

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
DirectroyIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will populate `path` query parameter in `/index.php` with the URI path `content/somepage.html`.

---

Or else use `FallbackResource`:

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

and use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable in your `/index.php` to get original URI.

Comment: Any reason not to use `FallbackResource` instead of mod_rewrite ?

Comment: yes I haven't used it but can I use FallbackResource /index.php instead of RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: @anubhava I put FallbackResource /index.php in .htaccess but when I say http://localhost/ it works fine but with **http://localhost/sample/contentabc** it redirects to wamp server home page.  If I run and host it from server it says **The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**.    I need contentabc or atleast the entire url which I can parse it.

Comment: @anubhava it works locally but the sample code I tried hosting in azure websites it gives **The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable**

Comment: On my Apache also it works fine. I have no idea how your azure websites is setup. What is Apache version, what is DocumentRoot, where is this .htaccess etc.

Comment: @anubhava one more issue which I didn't notice I am able to get the value after / but its not executing other things in index.php page when there is something is present after /

Comment: What is the full URL that is not working and what is exact error?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about can be achieved by using `.htaccess` for `url routing`.

Sample

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^content/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?id=$1
```

**Update based on comment.**

In last line you can use ...

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Inside `index.php` file you shall be able to get the rest of the string as `$_GET['url'];`

Comment: hello Abdul, actually what ever comes after **www.example.com/** I need it. content word is just example which I gave but it can be anything

Comment: so how to get the value in index.php file

Comment: abdul, I still get 404 not found page

Comment: I put the code sample download link in my question. I am trying this from my wamp server